# Agregar archivos al gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Deseo saber ¿Cómo ignorar archivos o carpetas en el `.gitignore`, y también saber si cuando realice un `git push` me va a modificar el archivo `.gitignore` que se encuentra en el repositorio o sólo queda local para mi maquina?

Answer (score 5):

Si colocar estos archivos bajo el control de versiones sería un desperdicio de espacio en disco. Y lo que es peor, al tenerlos todos listados, podría distraerte de los cambios que realmente importan, necesitas decirle a Git que los ignore.

Lo que debes hacer es crear un archivo en el directorio raíz de tu proyecto llamado `.gitignore:`

Estos patrones le dicen a Git que ignore cualquier archivo o carpeta (Si alguno de estos archivos ya estaba siendo rastreado, Git seguirá rastreándolos.)

**Y esto aplicará sólamente para repositorio, estos archivos continuarán en tu máquina local.**

### Ejemplo

Supongamos que tienes en tu archivo: `.gitignore` lo siguiente

```
*.dat
resultados/
ignorarArchivo.txt
```

Esto ignorará todos los archivos que terminen en `.dat`, todos los archivos que se encuentren en la carpeta `resultados`, e ignorará el archivo `ignorarArchivo.txt`

Comment: Si, eso lo tengo creado e incluso ya ignoro algunos archivos. Lo que necesitaba saber era si yo ignoro un "archivo.xxx" y lo agrego al gitignore, si de aca a un tiempo necesito hacerle cambios a ese archivo, deberia borrarlo en ese momento del .gitignore no?

Comment: Si este "archivo.xxx" es necesario para tu proyecto no deberías ignorarlo, si necesitas hacerle cambios lo puedes hacer sin problema, y estos cambios solo van a quedar en tu máquina, porque en el repositorio no se van a ver reflejados estos cambios.

Comment: @francofernandez lo que decis no suena logico. Ignorar archivos se usa para no subir al repositorio archivos propios de tu ide, basura de compilacion y otras cosas no necesarias para otros programadores (o que son generadas por la ide). Entonces, porque querrias designorar un archivo? en general el gitignore no lo tocas nunca (salvo para ignorar mas cosas)

Comment: porque en realidad me pasa que cuando realizo un git status me tira lo siguiente:
        modificado:     componentes/jcl/bin/JCL-install.ini
 modificado:     componentes/jcl/bin/JediInstaller.exe
 modificado:     componentes/jvcl/bin/JVCLCmdStarter.exe
 modificado:     componentes/jvcl/bin/JVCLInstall.exe
 borrado:        componentes/wst
 modificado:     fuentes/ATP/F_SpoolVentas.dfm
 modificado:     fuentes/ATP/PlgATP.dof
 modificado:     fuentes/OpticaRecetas/PlgOpticaRecetas.dof
 modificado:     iconos/Thumbs.db

Comment: Lo que quiero es borrar de esa lista por ejemplo "componentes/wst" para que no me figure mas alli pero sin borrar el archivo y sin hacer un git add

Comment: Te recomiendo simplemente que agreges la carpeta que quieres ignorar bien sea "componentes" o "wst"

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos